# How can I display if a process is running on my web page?

Tags: html, linux

I want to be able to display on my web page whether or not a process is running. Both run on the same system (Ubuntu server).

Basically, if something like the command ps -u game | grep java returns something, I want the site to display something like "Game Server Online", else "Offline."

I figure I could redirect the grep output to a file every 5 mins and have a script on the main page read the file content as a string to determine what to print. I feel as though there is be a much better way to do this, however. What else could I do and which scripting language would be best for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If php is available, you could do something like this inline in your page:

```php
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ps -u game | grep java');
if ($output === "java something") {
    echo "Server running"
} else {
    echo "Server not running"
}
?>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want to do! I'm a relatively novice programmer so I guess it'll be good to start learning some PHP now. Could an if/else statement and a string alter how a page is rendered (ex: render a table background green if string is not null)?

Comment: absolutely --see my edit. I've left it intentionally simple so you can see how it works and modify its behavior to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

what about a simple web service call?
calling a web service would ensure that both the server is up and the process is running.